# VLC for macOS command line audio delay

Tags: macos, command-line, vlc-media-player

I have a bunch of videos that have both audio and subtitles delayed by half a second. I can play them on VLC and manually adjust it by pressing F 10 times and H 10 times, but I'd like to automate that for those files and I'm trying to figure out a way of doing that via command line.

I've set up this alias on my environment:

```
alias vlc='/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC'
```

And I've read the help from `vlc -H`, but it doesn't seem to have a clear way of describing how to delay the audio.

So, this is the command I've got so far:

```
vlc \
--sub-delay -5 \
--delay-time -500 \
~/Desktop/My\ Video\[720x480\]\ s04e20\.mp4
```

The `sub-delay` works perfectly (in 1/10s increments), but the sound doesn't seem to do anything. The help says:

```
 Sound Delay (chorus_flanger)
 Add a delay effect to the sound
      --delay-time <float>       Delay time
          Time in milliseconds of the average delay. Note average
```

I don't think it means what I thought it meant, because of the "average" keyword. The only mention of "audio delay" concerns the key binding for that feature.

What is the correct parameter to define audio delay?

My files have multiple audio channels, it's currently playing the track set as default, and that's the one I'd like to fix during execution.

Thanks!

Comment: churus_flanger are audio 'special effects', both of which work by playing the original sound plus a short delay, which varies longer & shorter over time, to give a sense of movement. To steal a quote… these are not the droids you are looking for. I don't **know** what you do need, but I found `# Audio desynchronisation compensation (integer) #audio-desync=0` & `# Delay (integer) #sout-display-delay=100` either of which might prove to be useful.